# How to get the closest matches first from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of 10 million records and and am trying to select user details like firstname, lastname and country. I need to get results back in order where (order by column="abc") would give me results where those that match are ranked on the top.

**what I have tried**

Query one

```
-- this is match slower with 45+ seconds
select firstname, lastname, town
from user_db
order by town="abc" DESC
limit 25;
```

Query two

```
-- much faster with 0.00019 seconds
select firstname, lastname, town
from user_db
order by town DESC
limit 25;
```

**The problem**

The first query also works but takes 45+ seconds while if I remove the equals expression in the (order by clause) like in the second query, it's match faster. And obviously I do use where clauses but this is a simplified example.

other notes

There are currently no joins on the query as it is just a simple select statment of user details and my setup is pretty good with 30GB ram and 2TB of storage all local.

*Indexes: All columns mentioned have indexes but the (order by town="abc") clause triggers a full table search and as a result, this ends up finishing in 2 minutes*

Is there a way to get results ranked by closest matches first faster within a single query?
Any help will gladly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you investigated and ruled out [FULLTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) searching?

Comment: did you also try:  `select firstname, lastname, town from user_db where town="abc" order by town DESC limit 25;`

Comment: or a subquery ?

Comment: "...I need to get results back in order where (order by column="abc")..." -- So, basically you need to show the matches first, and then any other non-matching rows, for a total of 25 rows. Is that it?

Comment: Please [edit] your queston to show us the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE user_db;`, that is the definition of your table.

Comment: Seems you guys haven't exactly read the question fully yet I made every effort to make it so brief. The output of the query is normal and No error whatsoever but the cost is high from 45 seconds to almost 2 minutes

Comment: @TheImpaler, Yes you correct. Basically. I already have the results. I just wanna order them  from the most relevant with (order by column="") but takes way to long

Comment: @TheImpaler, Am not truly sure what you don't understand. What's not clear about the question.?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to establish with `order by town="abc"`. do you want to order by `town` is there an index on town`?

Comment: All columns got indexes on them. All of them

Comment: The expression `town="abd"`will result in a boolean value of true/false which you can certainly sort by but that would not be very efficient as it won have an index. You want to select all records with town equal `abc` you should use a where clause

Comment: @theking2, I can't add (where town="abc") simply because that would defeat my query logic and only return those that are equal to "abc".

Comment: And btw. adding an `explain` in front of the query will show i MySQL uses any of your indexes. Are we talking MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: To simplify this, I need a way to rank results, say on column town. order town alphabeticatically; But without taking too long as demostrate in my examples

Comment: @theking2, Yes Explain says "using filesort"

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by closest match? Do you mean to get tupples with town names starting with "abc"? Have you tried `like`.

Comment: @theking2, closest match alphabetically. Actually it's already been accomplished with (order by column='something'). But this technique disregards the use of indexes and thus resolves to full table scan on big tables.

Comment: I have also found out that mysql fails to use indexes when expressions are used in the order by clause too. expressions like (order by column='something'). Is there any other way to get results on a big table while still sorting.?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `user_db` table has an index on your `town` column. That means `ORDER BY town DESC LIMIT 25` can be satisfied in O(1) constant time by random-accessing the index to the last row and then scanning 25 rows of the index.

But your `ORDER BY town='abc' DESC LIMIT 25` has to look at, and sort, *every single row* in the table. MySQL doesn't use an index to help compute that `town='abc'` condition when it appears in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Many people with requirements like yours use [FULLTEXT searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and ordering by the [MATCH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match) function. That gets a useful ordering for a person looking at the closest matches like in the searching location bar of a web browser. But don't expect Google-like match accuracy from MySQL.

Comment: Many other forums have suggested that I use FULLTEXT searching but can you provide a working example perhaps.? Cuz I've tried it and got almost the same delay

Comment: See how a (`FULLTEXT index`)[https://database.guide/how-the-match-function-works-in-mysql/] work.

Answer (score 1):

You can decouple the query into two queries each one being very fast.

First, create an index on `town`.

```
create index ix1 on user_db (town);
```

Then get the matches, with a limit of 25 rows:

```
select * from user_db where town = 'abc' limit 25
```

The query above may return any number of rows between 0 and 25: let's call this number R. Then, get the non-matches:

```
select * from user_db where town <> 'abc' limit 25 - R
```

Assemble both result sets and problem solved. Even if the second query results in a table scan, it will be concluded earlier resulting in a low cost.

Comment: If this will be a common type of query, hide it in a Stored Procedure, where you can do the IF that is needed.  But be aware that the SP would be delivering either one or two resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a new column that has a value of country="abc", then sort by this column.

I'm rebuilding my workspace right now so I cannot try it properly, but something like:

```
select firstname, lastname, town, town="abc" as sortme
from user_db
order by sortme desc, town, lastname, firstname
limit 25;
```

Comment: I fear this will trigger the same full table scan as the one triggered in the question.

Comment: Every user has a column called town with their own actual town inside. But I need fetch users that have a specific town first then the rest. This means that those with the specific town will rank higher up in the results.

Comment: As indicated in my examples, (order by column='something') works but only on small tables

Comment: @Dennisrec sometimes a subtle change can make a difference. Note I am sorting on a computed column.  Again, I have not tried it, but it is a somewhat different approach.

Answer (score 0):

While it is unclear what you mean by "closest match" it is difficult to answer your question. Are "abd", "bc" etc regarded a close match to "abc"? Should the word "abc" appear in the town and match "abcville"?

There are a number of options.

### Appearance of search string

Using a like "%abc%" where clause will find all towns with the string "abc" appearing in it.

```
select firstname, lastname
from user_db
where town like "%abc%"
order by town
```

Leave out the first % if you want to search by towns starting with "abc". The advantage is that this probably will search in the index if there is one for `town`. Use `"abc%"` to find towns **starting** with "abc". There is no ranking but you could add a sort.

### Use a fulltext index

Create a FULLTEXT index on town:

```
ALTER TABLE user_db
ADD FULLTEXT(town);
```

And use this with a match:

```
SELECT 
  MATCH(town) AGAINST('abc') AS Relevance,
  firstname, lastname
FROM user_db
WHERE MATCH(town) AGAINST('abc')
ORDER BY Relevance DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Match uses *words* to calculate the match so in this case the string "abc" must appear with spaces in in the town in order to have a match. The `NATURAL LANGUAGE` options work well for plain texts but might not do so for town names.
To be honest I have no experience with FULLTEXT and `match` performance but it probably is well optimized and works fairly good on large tables.

### Create additional fields

As storage is cheap and time is not you might want to consider adding additional fields with search strings or alternative spellings for 'town' create all the indexes you'll need and use that as a search source. As this will need analysis of your use case it is difficult to provide an solution.